# parse C++ snippet using ANTLR and getting compiler errors

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I am following a tutorial and trying to parse some simple code snippet using ANTLR but I cannot do so, I get a lot of compile time errors that I cannot resolve, I am posting a screenshot of the errors that I am getting in my IDE.

[image]

```
  package cplusplusparser;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
  import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
  import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;
  import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNode;

  import cplusplusparser.CPP14Parser.AbstractdeclaratorContext;
  import cplusplusparser.CPP14Parser.TranslationunitContext;

  import org.antlr.v4.*;
  import org.antlr.*;
  import org.antlr.runtime.tree.ParseTree;



 public class UppercaseMethodListener extends CPP14BaseListener {

private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

// ... getter for errors

 @Override
public void enterMethodDeclarator(AbstractdeclaratorContext ctx) {
    TerminalNode node = ctx.Identifier();
    String methodName = node.getText();

    if (Character.isUpperCase(methodName.charAt(0))) {
        String error = String.format("Method %s is uppercased!", methodName);
        errors.add(error);
    }
}
// ... getter for errors
static String javaClassContent = "public class SampleClass { void DoSomething(){} }";
static CPP14Lexer java8Lexer = new CPP14Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(javaClassContent));
static CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(java8Lexer);
static CPP14Parser parser = new CPP14Parser(tokens);
static TranslationunitContext tree = parser.translationunit(); 

static ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
static UppercaseMethodListener listener= new UppercaseMethodListener();

  public static void main (String []args ) {
   walker.walk(listener, tree);

    assertThat(listener.getErrors().size(), is(1));
    assertThat(listener.getErrors().get(0),
      is("Method DoSomething is uppercased!"));
   }
}
```

Comment: I recommend checking out [Why not upload images of code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) (includes errors too)

Comment: All I see on the screenshot is a bunch of squiggly lines. Please post the actual error messages. At a glance it looks suspicious that your comment promises a getter method that you never define and that you have what looks like unit testing code in your main method.